# Call a javascript function if user is not scrolling a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to call javaScript  function if user is not scrolling a div with id `scrollingDiv`. this is how i thought

```js
function isScrolling() {
  if(<<isScrollingDiv>>) { 
    alert('Scrolling');
  } else {
    userNotScrolling();
}
isScrolling();
```

```html
<div style="overflow:scroll" id="scrollingDiv">SomeContent</div>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want? In which moment it should check scrolling? What will happen, if after check it'll run `userNotScrolling` and then user will scroll div?

Comment: dear i need to call the fuction if user is not scrolling

Comment: i need to scroll the user bottom of div. i can do that but at first i need to check is user is scrolling. so  i need to check if user is scrolling if no then i will call the function where the scrollbar set to bottm

Comment: please, i do't want if scrolling... i need if not scrolling with if else condition

Comment: Just create variable `isScrollingDiv = false`; set it to `true`, if user scroll div (you can use code by @Goliadkin); then check this variable in your `isScrolling`

Answer (score 0):

Check [jQuery's on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) functionality.

You could do something like this:

```
$('#scrollingDiv').on('scroll', function() {
    //do something while the user is scrolling the div
})
```

Comment: `.bind()` has been deprecated, so its use was already discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jquery you could use `scroll` event like :

```
$('#scrollingDiv').on('scroll', function() {
     console.log('User scrolling the div');
})
```

or also :

```
$('#scrollingDiv').scroll(function() {
     console.log('User scrolling the div');
});
```

Hope this helps.